# How to get all onNext values in array together?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Below I have code that makes a request to two API endpoints. I'm looking for a way to have the `onNext()` function only fire once. Right now if you run the code below, you can see it `logs` `fire 1`, then `fire 2`. I only want it to fire once, with the contents from both in an array.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import Rx from 'rx'
import assert from 'assert'

describe('rx axios', () => {
  it('should make http request to api', (done) => {
    let array = ['http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1', 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2']

    function httpGet(url) {
      return axios.get(url)
    }

    let source = Rx.Observable
    .fromArray(array)
    .concatMap(httpGet)

    let count = 0

    let subscription = source.subscribe(
      function (responses) {
        console.log(`fire ${count}`)
        count++
        // assert.equal(responses[0].data.name, 'Leanne Graham')
        // assert.equal(responses[1].data.name, 'Ervin Howell')
      },
      function (err) {
        done(err)
      },
      function () {
        done()
    })

  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`toArray`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/toarray.md). So for example :

```
 let source = Rx.Observable
    .fromArray(array)
    .concatMap(httpGet)
    .toArray()
```

I believe `toArray` also made its way to RxJs v5, but if you are using that version, don't take my word for it and check it. I am using v4.